# Autoware 1.13 Lane_planner / velocity profile

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I think I have a quite simple question, but I can not find a solution or anything in the documentation.

Until know I used mainly the OpenPlanner or recorded waypoints with a velocity. Now I would like to use the lane_planner and waypoint_planner. But I have issues with the velocity control, my vehicle does not slow down in front of curves. Which node is responsible for the calculation of the velocity profile of the waypoints based on the curvature?

Autoware version 1.13.
ROS Melodic

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best,
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343278/autoware-1.13-lane_planner-/-velocity-profile/) by [mschratter](https://answers.ros.org/users/51444/mschratter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@mschratter The `waypoint_replanner` node handles this function. You need to set `replan_curve_mode` to `true` and the `radius_thresh` and `radius_min` parameters. You can launch the `waypoint_loader`, `waypoint_replanner`, and `waypoint_marker_publish` by using the `waypoint_loader.launch` file from the `waypoint_maker` package.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0